# tikz grid in pgfplots axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to use `grid` in an axis environment, however it does not work as expected:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal, xmin=-1, xmax=10, ymin=-1, ymax=10,]
\draw[step=10mm] (0,0) grid (9,9);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does this not show a 10x10 grid?

Comment: After version 1.11 or so, all coordinates are taken as `axis cs:`  coordinates by default.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I fix this then?

Comment: Fix what? Does `grid=major` give you what you want?

Comment: Your code gives exactly the expected result. As percusse already stated, using `compat=1.11` or higher makes TikZ coordinates use axis coordinates by default. Thus, stating `\draw[step=10mm] (0,0) grid (9,9);` draws a grid from axis coordinates (0,0) to (9,9) in steps of 10mm. As marmot already stated, most likely you want to use `grid=major` eventually together with `xtick distance=<value>` and/or `ytick distance=<value>`.

Comment: No, I don't wanna use `grid=major` as I need a tikz grid in a non MWE project. I just expected the grid to start at (0,0) e.g. the corner should be at coordinate (0,0) which is not the case. I also expected 10 cells. Is 1 unit in `axis: cs` not `10mm`?

Comment: No, why would it be? (Consider that `pgfplots` is made for plotting data with all sorts of ranges, it doesn't make sense to set 1 axis unit to 1cm.) But if you set `width=11cm,height=11cm,scale only axis`, then your specific axis will have 1cm per axis unit. Edit: because both x- and y-axis have a range of 11, from -1 to 10.

Comment: You could load `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` and then do `\draw let \p1=($(9,9)-(0,0)$),\n1={0.1*\x1} in 
 (0,0) grid[step={\n1}] (9,9);` to get a 10x10 grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `axis equal` and set the `x` and `y` unit explicitely:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=10, ymin=-1, ymax=10,x=10mm,y=10mm]
\draw[step=10mm] (-.001,-.001) grid (9,9);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you could use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to draw the lines of the grid:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal, xmin=-1, xmax=10, ymin=-1, ymax=10]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,9}{\draw(#1,0)--(#1,9)(0,#1)--(9,#1);}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]